# How can we populate a List in an object using Linq?

Tags: linq-to-entities

The class "PaginatedReport" has two members :

```
int TotalResults;  
IList<Report> Reports;
```

I try to populate an instance of this class using this query :

```
var reports = (from r in _db.Report
               where r.res_id == status
               group r by r.res_id into g
               select new PaginatedReport
               {
                   TotalResults = g.Count(),
                   Reports = g.OrderBy(x =>x.res_id).Skip(start).Take(nb).ToList()
               });
```

How can I correct the query to avoid the following error :
Linq to entitites do not recognize the method "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DAL.Report]
ToList[Report](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DAL.Report])", and this method cannot be translated into a store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the last step (a `Select` returning an anonymous type) locally, rather than having the LINQ provider try and translate it into (presumably) SQL. Something like:

```
var reports = from g in (from r in _db.Report
                         where r.res_id == status
                         group r by r.res_id).AsEnumerable()
              select new PaginatedReport {
               TotalResults = g.Count(),
               Reports = g.OrderBy(x =>x.res_id).Skip(start).Take(nb).ToList()
              };
```

(and you don't need parentheses around the whole expression).

Comment: New problem with this query :  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PaginatedReport>' to 'ReportManagement.PaginatedReport'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Spilarix Without knowing your types one cannot help with that. With LINQ, unless an operator that returns a single element (like `First`) or aggregate (like `Sum`) is used, the result will always be `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQuery<T>` with `T` determined by the final step.